# Event Scheduled Reminders set for *Before* start dates won't send to participants registering *After* the start date

Tags: civievent, scheduled-reminders

I'm hoping to confirm that I understand the following correctly, based on [this description](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/365#note_8253):

1. I have an event with a scheduled reminder set to go at a certain time *before* the event. A contact who registers after that time, and before the event starts, will get the scheduled reminder. A contact who registers at *any* time *after* the event will *not* get the scheduled reminder. Is this correct?
2. After that, if I set up a scheduled reminder to go at a certain time *after* the event, then *all* event participants will get that email once that time has passed. Is that also correct?
3. Further, point 2 is true even if I set up the scheduled reminder *after that time has passed*. Is this also correct?

Thanks for your help! (Civi 5.24.4, Drupal 7.70)

PS - apologies if I've missed something in the documentation that answers this level of detail. I looked [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/scheduled-reminders/) without success.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes.  If you have a reminder 2 weeks before saying "Just 2 weeks before our fabulous event ..." then you don't want that being sent to your last-minute registrants.

2) Yes.  Your before and after reminders are independent.

3) Not sure, but I doubt it.  If you set it *before* the sending time then it would be sent.  ie if it is now one week after the event and you configure something to go out 2 weeks after the event it should work.

[Small updates to the docs](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-civicrm-community/contributing-to-this-manual/) are easy so if you can add useful information there, please do.

Comment: as I read it, in 1/ Andy is saying they 'will' get this, and you are saying in 1/'yes' but that 'you don't want that being sent' - not sure as I read it that the answer quite fits. could just be me

Comment: To the question "is this correct?": I'm saying yes, that's correct that someone who registers after the event will not get a reminder set for sometime before the event.  However, re-reading the question I was answering as if the 2nd sentence of 1) said they will _not_ get the mail, along with a reason why.  But you're right - that's not what Andy is saying.  Now I'm questioning whether they get the mail or not too!